# HTML forms - nested dropdowns?

Tags: html, forms

I don't know what this is called, so here's an image of what I want to do in an HTML form:

[image]

I want to select from a dropdown.  As I scroll down the list, I want to show subordinate selections, like you do in this example from Windows.  And use that final selection as the input to the form.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but most likely you'll have to use a third party library.
This menu is called **context menu**.

Checkout the library below

http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html

If you just want to put input in a form then probably it's better to use a simple dropdown.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a dropdown menu with submenus

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to implement something like this. You will get many codes in google if you simply search for a multilevel drop down navigation menu.

```css
ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
}

ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

ul li.active
{
 background:#ddd
}

ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1 &#9658;</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 &#9658;</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2 &#9658;</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fair enough, the suggestion to use the jQuery contextMenu plugin really is not bad. It can handle submenu's for you without a problem and really makes defining the command's quite a lot easier than writing it yourself.

http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/sub-menus.html